# Calculate number knowing how much is a percentage of it

Tags: percentages

So, the question is, how to calculate the total number of players if I'm the 207th , placed 0.0167% of top.

Comment: Suppose you were $4$th and were in the top $2\%$, what do you think the total number might be?

Comment: @Henry I guess that would be 200, since 2 would be 1% , so 200. Thanks for pointing it out, really simple after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a discrete uniform distribution on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ where $n$ is the total number of players. You have $\mathbb{P}[X\le 207]=0.0167\%$. You also have $\mathbb{P}[X\le k]=\frac{k}{n}$, so that you have $n\approx\frac{207}{0.0167\%}=1239520.95808$

Answer (score 1):

Say there are $100x$ players. 
Then according to your position, 
$0.0167x=207 \Rightarrow 100x \approx 1239520$